# Index for Analytic Function First_Value

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2014

I can't figure out what kind of index I need to create in order for the following query to not cause TWO sorts in the execution plan.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    col_A,
    FIRST_VALUE (col_B) OVER (PARTITION BY col_A ORDER BY col_C DESC) AS x
FROM table_A
```

The primary key on the table is on col_A, col_C, and this is the current execution plan:
[image]

Is there a way to get rid of the two sorts?

Comment: Have you tried using the Database Engine Tuning Advisor?

Comment: A shot in the dark: `CREATE INDEX IDX_xyz ON table_A (col_A, col_C DESC)  INCLUDE (col_B)`

Comment: I just don't know you are going to get out of two sorts.  It is not going to know FIRST_VALUE (col_B) until after it does the over.    If you have in index on col_A, col_C DESC that should be a fast sort.  Are you having a performance problem?

Comment: @ZoffDino Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: @Blam It's not slow per se, but mostly for the sake of learning more about how indexes work with queries like this. I know that the sort distinct is inevitable, but was curious if there was a way to have the data pre-sorted for an analytic function.

Comment: @Stephan It did not give me any suggestions, but I did not know about this program until now! Good to keep in my back pocket for future performance tuning needs.

Comment: Wow. I'm surprised it didn't give you anything. And it is a very nice tool that no one seems to know about...

Answer (score 1):

I tried a similar query over a table with about 700.000 rows (producing 25.000 rows as the result). In the next to last step, I get a "Hash Match (Aggregate)", instead of a "Sort (Distinct Sort)". Without any index (except the clustered index), the second step is a sort on Col_A, Col_C.

After creating an index as suggested by Zoff Dino, the sort is not needed anymore (only the Hash Match remains).

However, I get a better plan (and slightly shorter execution time) for the following query (which should provide the same results):

```
SELECT col_A, x FROM (
    SELECT col_A, 
        FIRST_VALUE(col_B) OVER (PARTITION BY col_A ORDER BY col_C) AS x, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col_A ORDER BY col_C) AS RowNum 
    FROM table_A
) q 
WHERE RowNum=1
```